# Making text appear in a box

Tags: boxes, code

Sorry if this is similar to previous questions, but I need to check if this is the best solution. My issue is that I am writing a document which contains HTTP messages for example of a snippet:

```
   message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
   field-name     = token
   field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
   field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                    and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                    of token, separators, and quoted-string>
```

much like when using this website the message appears in a grey box is there a best practice way to do this in latex? I have found the following link:
[Box or sidebar for additional text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99809/box-or-sidebar-for-additional-text)
and was wondering whether this is the best solution. I was also hoping to omit the text from a wordcount if possible. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - I am hoping for the following kind of effect:
[image]

Comment: I really do not understand what are you after. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate? [Source code listing with frame around code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14967) On the counting issue, word counting is really hard in TeX, but the `texcount` program does a pretty usable job and is able to selectively remove environments from the count.

Comment: @AlanMunn: The linked post seem to require the addition of a caption, which this question does not. But that might be splitting hairs.

Comment: @Werner well caption or not the basic principle seems to be the same.  Alternatively [How to make a box containing LaTeX output?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21084) but I think the first one is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)'s `listings` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only}
message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
field-name     = token
field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                 and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                 of token, separators, and quoted-string>
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```