# titled box or sidebar (of variable width) for additional text?

Tags: tcolorbox, wrapfigure

Inspired by [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99809/box-or-sidebar-for-additional-text) I was looking to create a convenient command for a titled sidebar of variable width.

Thus far I have solved half the problem.  The following code gives a title, but I haven't yet got the variable width worked out...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{SideBox}[1]
  {\wrapfigure{#1}{0.5\textwidth} \tcolorbox[title=#1]}
  {\endtcolorbox\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{SideBox}{A fancy title}
  text inside the box
\end{SideBox}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the code to get variable width via a command like:

```
\begin{SideBox}{0.3}{A fancy title}
  text inside the box
\end{SideBox}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{SideBox}[3][]
  {\wrapfigure{#3}{#2\textwidth} \tcolorbox[title=#3,width={#2\textwidth},#1]}
  {\endtcolorbox\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{SideBox}[colbacktitle={yellow},colback={white!70!yellow},coltitle={black},fonttitle={\large\bfseries}]{0.3}{A fancy title}
  text inside the box
\end{SideBox}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Some 'improvements' **

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mysidebox}[1][]{%
  nobeforeafter,
  colbacktitle={yellow},
  colback={white!70!yellow},
  coltitle={black},
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  #1,
}

\newenvironment{SideBox}[4][]
  {\wrapfigure{#4}{#2\textwidth}\mysidebox[title=#3,width={#2\textwidth},#1]}
  {\endmysidebox\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{SideBox}{0.3}{A fancy title}{r}
  text inside the box
\end{SideBox}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{SideBox}[enhanced,sharp corners,drop shadow={green}]{0.4}{A fancy title}{l}
  text inside the box
\end{SideBox}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Q: I saw the pre-edit version with `\newenvironment{SideBox}[2]`. What was the value of extending this to 3 input params? Is that to facilitate other options (like being yellow) when calling sidebox?

Comment: @Mark_Anderson: I have thought about the possibility of changing the `tcolorbox` options, which are given as first optional argument, i.e. `\SideBox[options for tcolorbox]{width}{Title}`

Comment: I've used `wrapfigure` wrong, however